# Dynamic expand UITextView

Tags: ios, ios4, uitextview

I have UITextView and I want to expand it dynamically. If the text is should scroll I want to expand the view to fit the amount of the text. How can I do that. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you end the editing of your text write this.

```
- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect frame = myTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = myTextView.contentSize.height;
    myTextView.frame = frame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find the heightof the text you need to contain inside the UITextView (of a particular fixed width)  and then set its frame height to that value so that it is not scrollable. You can go through this [example](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/truncate-an-nsstring-and-append-an-ellipsis-respecting-the-font-size.html) to see how exactly to do that.