# iPhone: UITextView not expanding while editing

Tags: ios, xcode4, uitextview

I am using UITextView on a scroll view ...and I want it to auto expand when I write something in it ...... but I am unable to do it ...

```
textViewBusiness = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,332,268,60)];
textViewBusiness.text=strMyBusiness;
textViewBusiness.editable=NO;
textViewBusiness.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 17.0];
textViewBusiness.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
textViewBusiness.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
textViewBusiness.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[textViewBusiness setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.scrollView addSubview: textViewBusiness];

CGRect frame = textViewBusiness.frame;
frame.size.height = textViewBusiness.contentSize.height;
textViewBusiness.frame = frame;
```

This code is not working for me ...

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the text field's delegate is set...

```
someTextField.delegate = self;
```

Then adjust the size of the textView in the appropriate text field delegate method.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;

- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

The code you've added above is correct. Just make sure it's in the correct place.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
   CGRect frame = textView.frame;
   frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
   textView.frame = frame;
 }
```

[Dynamic expand UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186035/dynamic-expand-uitextview)

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work.

You need to divide your code into 2 fragments, then place them into proper places, then your code should work.

Fragment 1 (in my test, I place this fragment in viewDidLoad):

```
textViewBusiness = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,332,268,60)];
textViewBusiness.text=strMyBusiness;
textViewBusiness.editable=NO;
textViewBusiness.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 17.0];
textViewBusiness.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
textViewBusiness.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
textViewBusiness.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[textViewBusiness setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.scrollView addSubview: textViewBusiness];
```

Ensure that the above fragment run, and your text view is displayed in the screen, then run the second fragment. If your text view is not displayed in the screen, then the contentView is not initialized, and the height is undefined.

Fragment 2 (in my test, I place this fragment in viewDidAppear):

```
CGRect frame = textViewBusiness.frame;
frame.size.height = textViewBusiness.contentSize.height;
textViewBusiness.frame = frame;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[`HPGrowingTextView`](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/hpgrowingtextview) is a `UITextView` which grows/shrinks with the text and starts scrolling when the content reaches a certain number of lines. Similar to the one Apple uses in the SMS-app. See the link for a small (outdated) screencast.