# Expand UITextView and UITableView When UITextView's Text Extends Beyond 1 Line

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITableView with two UITextViews side by side inside each of the cells. I want both the UITableViewCell and UITextView to increase in height so that the user doesn't need to scroll within the UITextView. Here is what I've tried:

In the TableViewController Class:

```
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In the TableViewCell Class (got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186035/dynamic-expand-uitextview)) :

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    var frame : CGRect = textView.frame
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
    textView.frame = frame
}
```

When the user types beyond the set width of the UITextView, the UITableView increases height from 44 to about 100 and the UITextView doesn't increase in height. I have the constraints set up so that the UITextView's height is equal to that of the UITableViewCell.

Any ideas why this is happening and **how to correctly dynamically change the UITextView and UITableView's heights?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My answer is based on what we exactly use in production of our social app [Impether](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/impether/id1084468692), since you asked me on Twitter that you used the app and you saw expanding UITextView there.

First of all, we have a custom [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/) based class containing the `UITextView`, which will be expanded (this class has a corresponding xib file also, which you can design on your own):

```
class MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //our cell has also a title, but you
    //can get rid of it
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    //UITextView we want to expand
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    /// Custom setter so we can initialize the height of the text view
    var textString: String {
        get {
            return textView?.text ?? ""
        }
        set {
            if let textView = textView {
                textView.text = newValue
                textView.delegate?.textViewDidChange?(textView)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()        
        // Disable scrolling inside the text view so we enlarge to fitted size
        textView?.scrollEnabled = false        
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        if selected {
            textView?.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textView?.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Having a custom cell defined, you can use it in a `UITableViewController` based class like that:

```
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //in case where you want to have
    //multiple expanding text views
    var activeTextView: UITextView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //registering nib for a cell to reuse
        tableView.registerNib(
            UINib(nibName: "MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
            forCellReuseIdentifier: "MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell")

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        //hide keyboard when view controller disappeared
        if let textView = activeTextView {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        //put your value here
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //put your value here
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                            cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
            "MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell

        let titleText = "Title label for your cell"
        let textValue = "Text value you want for your text view"

        cell.titleLabel.text = titleText
        cell.textView.text = textValue

        //store row of a cell as a tag, so you can know
        //which row to reload when the text view is expanded
        cell.textView.tag = row
        cell.textView.delegate = self

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                            estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        //standard row height
        return 44.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                            heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                            canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
}

//extension containing method responsible for expanding text view
extension YourTableViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        let value = textView.text
        //you can do something here when editing is ended
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange,
                  replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        //if you hit "Enter" you resign first responder
        //and don't put this character into text view text
        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        activeTextView = textView
    }

    //this actually resize a text view
    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

        let size = textView.bounds.size
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width,
            height: CGFloat.max))

        // Resize the cell only when cell's size is changed
        if size.height != newSize.height {
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            tableView?.beginUpdates()
            tableView?.endUpdates()
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

            let thisIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: textView.tag, inSection: 0)
            tableView?.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(thisIndexPath,
                                              atScrollPosition: .Bottom,
                                              animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't seem to get it to work I have two textViews side-by-side. Neither has a height constraint set to it, but one has a width constraint. I tried turning scrolling enabled on and the cell still doesn't expand, the textView just gets pushed up to accommodate for the new line. Any ideas?

Comment: Saved my goddamn day!

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your auto layout constraint doesn't conflict with frame you set. (If everything is OK but still doesn't work) Then try changing `frame` to `bounds`. A view's frame (CGRect) is the position of its rectangle in the superview's coordinate system. Using `frame` may cause strange problem sometimes in my experience.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    var frame : CGRect = textView.bounds
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
    textView.bounds = frame
}
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. My textViews are side by side and don't have a height constraint set to them. Should I call the textViewDidChange in my custom cell class and can the automatic row height in my tableVC?