# Swift / how to use UITextView with dynamic height INSIDE UITableViewCell with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using the following code to have the UITableViewCell have a dynamic height:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 155
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And this code to have the UITextView change it's height based on the content.

```
extension NewUserTweetTableVC: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
        textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
        var newFrame = textView.frame
        newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
        textView.frame = newFrame    
    }
}
```

Once I change the text of the UITextView during runtime, the height of the UITextView changes, but the height of the UITableViewCell does not. How can I change that? Help is very appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check this Q :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014919/expand-uitextview-and-uitableview-when-uitextviews-text-extends-beyond-1-line

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Get programmatically height of textview...

```
let textView = UITextView()//your Text view
let sizeThatShouldFitTheContent = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size)
let height = sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.height
```

OR try this demo...

**Self-sizing UITextView in a UITableView**

https://www.damienpontifex.com/posts/self-sizing-uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-in-ios8/

Comment: even tho stackoverflow dont want people just to post links, because links can go down, this actually helped me.

Comment: and now the link is down :(

Comment: The mentioned link is down

Comment: This link is back online, but I think it would be worth summarizing its contents here, because it did work brilliantly.  Most other answers listed here are only a piece in the puzzle.  In short, disable scrolling of the text view, make sure you can initialize your value on the text view so it will call textViewDidChange, then calculate if the height has changed, and if so, call begin/endUpdates on the tableView, while wrapping/sandwiching those calls in UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false/true)

Comment: This is really helpful... Thanks @rahul and rs7.

Comment: Thank. Your git is old code. but it's very good.

Answer (score 12):

Step 1, Disable Scrolling of TextView 
Step 2, Add Top, Left, Right and bottom constraint 
Step 3, Set Delegate to textView 
Step 4, Implement below UITextViewDelegate Method

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:false];
[textView sizeToFit];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:true];}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` then you must set serial constraints from top to bottom. Without autolayout or proper constraints `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` won't work. So you can manage this thing something like: `set top,bottom,leading,trailing and fixed height` constraints to your `textview`. then take outlet of `fixed height constraint` and increase it's `constant` instead changing or setting frame of textview and everythng will work I think!

Comment: need to disable scrolling of the text view

Comment: set top,bottom,leading,trailing, disable scroll. and all worked

Answer (score 5):

I am improving Lion's answer.

If you are using UITableViewAutomaticDimension then you must set serial constraints from top to bottom. Without autolayout or proper constraints UITableViewAutomaticDimension won't work. So you can manage this thing something like: set top,bottom,leading,trailing and fixed height constraints to your textview. Disable the scrolling feature of UITextview and you are done. You are not required to fixed height constraint.

Answer (score 5):

Update code in Swift 4.2
Credit: http://www.swiftdevcenter.com/the-dynamic-height-of-uitextview-inside-uitableviewcell-swift/ 
Create a Custom cell with name GrowingCell, add UITextView in the cell and create an Outlet of this. Register this cell in UITableView in your ViewController class.
Your ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "GrowingCell", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "GrowingCell")
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GrowingCell", for: indexPath) as! GrowingCell
        cell.cellDelegate = self
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: GrowingCellProtocol {
    // Update height of UITextView based on string height
    func updateHeightOfRow(_ cell: GrowingCell, _ textView: UITextView) {
        let size = textView.bounds.size
        let newSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width,
                                                        height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        if size.height != newSize.height {
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            tableView?.beginUpdates()
            tableView?.endUpdates()
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
            // Scoll up your textview if required
            if let thisIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
                tableView.scrollToRow(at: thisIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now move to your Custom GrowingCell cell and add below code:

```
import UIKit

protocol GrowingCellProtocol: class {
    func updateHeightOfRow(_ cell: GrowingCell, _ textView: UITextView)
}

class GrowingCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var cellDelegate: GrowingCellProtocol?
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}

extension GrowingCell: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if let deletate = cellDelegate {
            deletate.updateHeightOfRow(self, textView)
        }
    }
}
```

For more detail: [visit this full demo](http://www.swiftdevcenter.com/the-dynamic-height-of-uitextview-inside-uitableviewcell-swift/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable the scrolling of the text view to make the tableViewCell autoresize according to the content size of the textView.

Comment: This was the thing that made the auto-sizing work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it can help you or not, but I custom an UITextView that fitting the content height as its height.

This is the TextView from your UITableViewCell:

```swift
final class ContentFittingTextView: UITextView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

and from your UITableView:

```swift
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

Comment: This didn't work. Did you miss mentioning any other settings?