# How to set UITextView's height dynamically in UITableViewCell based on string size?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I understand that this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484944/swift-how-to-use-uitextview-with-dynamic-height-inside-uitableviewcell-with-dy), but it didn't solve my problem as the link in the accepted answer is down and the minimal example didn't help.

Here is a picture of my custom UITableViewCell & all its constraints:

[image]

Each post contains these UI elements. The only element that could make each cell's height different is `messageView`, because its height depends on the string being displayed. Question is, how do I dynamically set each cell's height? Here's what I have now (Does NOT work, `messageView` is not shown at all):

```
func cellForRowAt(indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...) as! PostCell

    let message = ...
    cell.messageView.text = message

    return cell
}

func heightForRowAt(indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var cellMinimumHeight: CGFloat = 120
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PostCell {
        let size = cell.messageView.sizeThatFits(cell.messageView.frame.size)
        cellMinimumHeight += size.height
    }

    return cellMinimumHeight
}
```

in `heightForRowAt` function, the `if` is not being executed, therefore, all cells' heights are `cellMinimumHeight = 120`.

**How could I make each cell's height = 120 + messageView's height?**

**---------------------------------EDIT 1---------------------------------**

Made a mistake in the picture, `messageView`'s height is not set

Comment: Will you change text in messageView? If not, why don't you use an UILabel instead?

Comment: @trungduc, Thank you for the reply. I use `UITextView` because I want to be able to detect emails, links, phone numbers in the message. UITextView provides such functionality

Comment: Did you set `scrollEnabled = false` of the `UITextView`?

Comment: @nayem, AWESOME!!! That solved the problem! Please post the answer below so I could accept it, unless you don't care about reputations (then I will post the answer later)

Comment: Hmm adding, just gimme a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Auto-Layout for dynamically sizing cells, you don't really need to implement `sizeThatFits(...)`. If the constraints are setup correctly, then you only need to disable the scrolling of the `UITextView`.

### From code:

```
yourTextView.scrollEnabled = false
```

### From IB:

Select your Text View and open *Attributes inspector*, then

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Attributes Inspector select your `UITextView(messageView)` and Uncheck "Scrolling Enabled".

And then change your `UITextView(messageView)'s` content compression resistence priority as follows:
Horizontal = 750
Vertical = 1000

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable UITextview scroll... 
But here is no use of UITextview, you can use label also.

In HeightForRow tableview delegate method remove that stuff and use

```
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used constrain to make cell hight dynamic

form apple documentation

> To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of constraints
>   and views (with defined heights) to fill the area between the content
>   view’s top edge and its bottom edge.

So for your case  you need

cell's height = 120 + messageView's height?

So start from Profile Image to measure  **unbroken chain of constraints** from Top to Bottom

1. Profile Image top = 10 + ImageHeight = 60   ---->  **70**
2. MessageView  top = 10 + set minimum height to message say 20 one line if every cell should have message even if one word and set this **height Greater than or equal to 20**  make sure that you **set Scroll enable = false**
   so message Height minimum  =   **10 top + 20 + 10 bottom ---> 40**
3. Menu Stack view Height ---> **30**

So all Total  = 70 + 40 + 30 = 140   this default hight no cell will be less than this

Also you must set the table view’s rowHeight property to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. You must also assign a value to the `estimatedRowHeight` property

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 130.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Here is apple documentation [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH25-SW1)